# how to get most common phrases or words in python or R

Tags: python, r, nlp, text-mining

Given some text, how can i get the most common n-gram across n=1 to 6?
I've seen methods to get it for 3-gram, or 2-gram, one n at a time, but is there any way to extract the max-length phrase that makes the most sense, and all the rest too?

for example, in this text for demo-purpose only: 
`fri evening commute can be long. some people avoid fri evening commute by choosing off-peak hours. there are much less traffic during off-peak.`

The ideal outcome of n-gram and their counter would be:

```
fri evening commute: 3,
off-peak: 2,
rest of the words: 1
```

any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: May be you can refer to this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107505/word-count-from-a-txt-file-program

Comment: This would depend on your meaning of "most sense" ... Unless you have a function which can validate if a n-gram makes sense or not this is not possible. Something like "food get" may not make sense to some but will make sense to others

Comment: I think he means to decrement the occurrences of an n-1 gram by the occurence of the n grams that include it with equal frequency

Comment: AbdealiJK I agree with u that 'make sense' is subjective and not straightforward. but like @Moody_Mudskipper mentioned, if start from a higher n, then i might trace to a sense-making phrase like 'food get stuck' as the recurring pattern, else if the article really details different 'food get' scenario like food get bad, food get into nostrils, then 'food get' is indeed a pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise this if you plan to use R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-usecase-postagging-lemmatisation.html

Comment: thanks. just wondering is there any reason the 3 methods mainly return bi-gram instead of higher n?

Comment: Look at the arguments of the keywords_ functions, it allows to set n to anything you like.

Answer (score 5):

**Python**

Consider the [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) library which offers an ngrams function that you can use to iterate over values of n.

A *rough* implementation would be along the lines of the following, where *rough* is the keywords here:

```
from nltk import ngrams
from collections import Counter

result = []
sentence = 'fri evening commute can be long. some people avoid fri evening commute by choosing off-peak hours. there are much less traffic during off-peak.'
# Since you are not considering periods and treats words with - as phrases
sentence = sentence.replace('.', '').replace('-', ' ')

for n in range(len(sentence.split(' ')), 1, -1):
    phrases = []

    for token in ngrams(sentence.split(), n):
        phrases.append(' '.join(token))

    phrase, freq = Counter(phrases).most_common(1)[0]
    if freq > 1:
        result.append((phrase, n))
        sentence = sentence.replace(phrase, '')

for phrase, freq in result:
    print('%s: %d' % (phrase, freq))
```

As for **R**

[This might be helpful](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/252523_e942d62813f142f6bc6d11c245e46d5a.html)

Comment: Would be interested to know if it is sclable. Nad what is the alternative for large text sets?