# Python code that counts the number of distinct words with a specific length in a file

Tags: python, file, cpu-word

I'm looking for a way in Python to write a function that, having two input(name of a text file and a natural number n), returns the number of all the distinct words in the file (House and HOUSE are two different words for example) with the length given in input

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. A Set is more appropriate than a list for coutning unique word.

```py
def f(filename: str, n: int) -> list:
    res = set()
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        for word in line.split(' '):
            if len(word) == n:
                res.add(word)
    return list(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Word count answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21107578/5811078) approach we can find all the words and their counts.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    wordcount = Counter(f.read().split())
```

Then, you can just filter the desired length:

```
n = 5
result = {k: v for k, v in result.items() if len(k) == n}
```