# Issues trying to count the words in a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to make this program work out but I am having some issues at the moment. I want this code to read the total amount of words across [this text file](https://pastebin.com/XwKzyDLE). This is what I have for now:

```
import os

openfile = input('Enter the input file: ')

accumulator = 0
accumulator2 = 0
accumulator3 = 0
accumulator4 = 0
word = 'PMID'
word2 = 'LA'
word3 = 'PT  - Journal'
try: 
    file = open(openfile, 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()

    with open(openfile, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if word in line:
                accumulator += 1

        if word2 in line:
            accumulator2 += 1

        if word2 in line:
            accumulator3 += 1

        if 'Journal' in line and 'LA' in line:
                accumulator4 += 1

    print('there are:',accumulator ,'PMID')
    print('there are:',accumulator2 ,'LA')
    print('there are:',accumulator3 ,'PT')
    print('there are:',accumulator4 ,'PT and LA')
    exit()

except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Input file not found.')
    print('Please check the file name or the location of your input file.')
```

I want it to also count the text blocks that have together "LA  - eng" "PT  - Journal Article" as one (like the third block). Is there a way to do this even though they are in different lines? Thank you so much!

Comment: you're reading the file twice.

you can remove the lines `file = open(openfile, 'r')` and `lines = file.readlines()`

Comment: do you want to count a word twice if it occurs twice in a line?

Comment: if you have alerady the variables `word`, `word2` and `word3` you should change the `print` lines as well e.g. `print('there are:',accumulator , word)`

Comment: The third if statement is wrong. You should write `if word3 in line:` not `if word2 in line:`

Comment: you might want to read about lists, so that your code is easily enhancable if you have only 1 word or much more words.

Comment: Also if hypothetically your text file would be so big, that it doesn't fit into your computers RAM it would be better to write following.
`with open(openfile, 'r') as f:` and then `for line in f:`
This way you would read and process line by line and the memory required by one line would be released before the next line is read.

In any case. I think it's always nice to write code that doesn't use more resources than are required to fulfil its task.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word count from a txt file program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107505/word-count-from-a-txt-file-program)

Comment: you had to define what you consider to be a text block.
And then you would require intermediate counters, that you analyze and reset as soon as you begin a new text block.

Comment: @TomServo. The mentioned link counts all words contained in the text and the script doesn't have the notion of a *text block* (which papara) has still to explain, so that the detection of two different words in the same block can be performed

Comment: not sure the close request is justified (question is a duplicate) . The question seems to have some variations on the existing questions. If there is really something, that answers this question, then perhaps add a reference to this answer. instead of just voting to close?

Answer (score 0):

This method I have from a course I took on Pluralsight some time ago, will output the number of instances of each word in the file. This is useful when working with sentiment analysis algorithms:

```
    results = dict()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                results[word] = results.setdefault(word, 0) + 1

    for word, count in sorted(results.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
        print('{} {}'.format(count, word))
```

You can run it like this in PyCharm Community version, having the file in the same directory as the project:

make sure the method is defined above the main check.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    count_words('word_file.txt')
```